# Problem in longPress() on web element in apium

Tags: automation, appium, long-press

I am using longpress() for my web element in apium and i am using ApiumDriver.
Below is the code and the error:

```java
TouchAction ac = new TouchAction(driver);

ac.longPress((LongPressOptions) sm).perform().release();
```

where sm is my web element, while error is as follows:

`Failed io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions`

Answer (score 1):

Inside `longPress` method you have to pass `AndroidElement` using `ElementOption`

```
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions.longPressOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

    WebElement someElement = 
     driver.findElement(By.id("someID"));
  // WAY 1
   TouchAction ac=new TouchAction(driver);
   ac.longPress(element(someElement)).perform().release();

  // WAY 2
    TouchAction dragNDrop = new TouchAction(driver)
            .longPress(longPressOptions()
                    .withElement(element(someElement))
                    .withDuration(ofSeconds(2)))
            .perform().release();
```